# Componente sensible a cambios en el backend

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

En la UI de mi app hay 2 listas y un form.

Una lista son equipos sin puntaje otorgado y la otra lista son los scores de los equipos ya cargados.

Cada lista se llena con información proveniente de sus respectivos métodos de mi propia API Rest.

El form recibe un `team_id` y un `score` y la idea es que al darle al botón, el equipo en cuestión desaparezca de la primera lista y aparezca en la segunda.

Teniendo en cuenta que las respuestas de la api van a parar a states diferentes del componente (`this.state.updatedTeams`, `this.state.nonUpdatedTeams`), ¿cómo hago para pasar un item de un estado al otro una vez que submiteo el form?

Este el código de mi componente:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.fetchUpdatedTeams = this.fetchUpdatedTeams.bind(this);
    this.fetchNonUpdatedTeams = this.fetchNonUpdatedTeams.bind(this);
    this.state= {
        nonUpdatedTeams : [
          
        ],
        updatedTeams : [

        ],
        eventId : 1,
        category_id: 1,
   
    }
   
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchNonUpdatedTeams();/* fetch API in action */    
  }
  fetchNonUpdatedTeams() {
    fetch('/api/event/'+this.state.eventId)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(teams => {   
            let teamsArray = teams;
           
             this.fetchUpdatedTeams();
            //Fetched product is stored in the state
             this.setState({ nonUpdatedTeams : teamsArray });
        });
  }
  fetchUpdatedTeams() {
    
    fetch('/api/event/'+this.state.eventId + '/scores')
    .then(response => {
        
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(eventResults => {
        let teamsArray = eventResults
        this.setState({ updatedTeams : teamsArray });
    });

  }

  setScore(team_id, score) {
    const teamScore = {
      team_id,
      score
    }
      let team = this.state.nonUpdatedTeams.find((aTeam)=> aTeam.id == team_id);
      const url = '/api/event/' + this.state.eventId+'/cargarScore/'
      axios.post(url,teamScore)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });;
      console.log(team)

      this.fetchNonUpdatedTeams()
      this.fetchUpdatedTeams()
    
  }

 render() {  

    let nonUpdatedTeams = this.state.nonUpdatedTeams
    let updatedTeams = this.state.updatedTeams
    updatedTeams = updatedTeams.sort(function(a, b){return a.score - b.score})
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Cargar Resultados</h1>
        </header>
        <Jumbotron>
          <h3>Evento: -id del Evento-</h3>
          <Form update={this.setScore.bind(this)}/>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Col className="column" md={6} sm={6}>
          <List  entries={nonUpdatedTeams}/>
        </Col>
        <Col className="column" md={6} sm={6}>  
          <List entries={updatedTeams}/>   
        </Col> 
       </div>
     
    );
    
  }
}
export default App;
const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootDiv );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```